# Implement Secure Authentication in MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I want to implement the secure authentication with maintaining the login data in subsequent requests.

I have planned to use form authentication but cookie generated from forms authentication, will be accessed by hacker or middle man. So if we use form authentication with the help of cookie user can login.

If we use session, which will also create the cookie in local and also create over head in server.

So how we can maintain user login details, which can be used in web app but (without SSL).

Comment: Why would you like to deploy a application without SSL nowadays with free solutions like lets-encrypt for your certificate? If it is local you can always consider a self-signed certificate.

Comment: if you are not using SSL, you are not safe in production no matter what your authentication mechanism is, sorry.

Comment: that means SSL provided free are secure ? Also whether JWT authentication will be secure comparatively?

Comment: That depends on what is free and secure. Self-signed certificate is free, but if you leak your root certificate it is not secure. If you look at lets-encrypt, yes that is secure, besides extra insurance benefits or domain validation (EV certificate) there is security wise no difference with other providers.

Comment: Can u please share those SSL details